# Making One Future Waiting For Another Future Before Going

Tags: scala

I am having problem. I am needing one future to wait for other future finished before running. My coding is like this:

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.Future

object Test {

  def foo = Future {
    // take big time to finishing
    Thread.sleep(10000)
    println("Doned foo")
  }

  def bar = Future {
    // some small tasks
    println("Doned bar")
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    for {
      _ <- foo
    } yield {
      for {
        _ <- bar
      } yield()
    }
  }

}
```

When am running this, I see nothing. What is wrong? And for loop looks bad. ANy advices on good solutions please.

Comment: You do not need a double for, just `val f = for { _ <- foo, _ <- bar } yield ()`. Second, if you run this on a **RELP** it works. I do not really know too much about futures, but probably the error is that since your main exit the whole program is shutdown and as such, you do not see any output. I know you can just `Await.ready(f, duration)` where _f_ would be the future returned by your for, and _duration_ is the maximum amount of time you are willing to wait for it to finish.  - Now, that seems pretty forced and will keep one thread blocked. Maybe there is a way to create daemon futures?

Answer (score 2):

Futures in Scala are evaluated eagerly and there is no easy way to make them lazy. One way is to wrap future creation in function and you that is what you do, so your problem is not connected with that.

What you do wrong, is that you start your futures, but then you don't wait for them and your application finishes before their evaluation is over. You'd have to add `Await.result` at the end of your `main` method.

Another thing you do unnecessarily is nesting for comprehensions. Every invocation in for comprehension is done sequentially (it translates to either `map` or `flatMap`), so `bar` would wait for `foo` to finish.

```
import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits._
import scala.concurrent.duration._

def foo = Future {
    // take big time to finishing
    Thread.sleep(1000)
    println("Doned foo")
}

def bar = Future {
    // some small tasks
    Thread.sleep(1000)
    println("Doned bar")
}

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val future = for {
      _ <- foo 
      _ <- bar //this future waits until foo is done
    } yield ()


    Await.result(future, 3000.millis)
}
```

Let's say you need to create execute, which one depends on another:

```
def foo1(): Future[String] = ???
def foo2(foo1: String): Future[String] = ??? //foo2 depends on foo1
def foo3(foo2: String): Future[String] = ??? //foo3 depends on foo2
```

It's simple as that:

```
for {
  f1 <- foo1()
  f2 <- foo2(f1)
  f3 <- foo3(f2)
  _  <- Future{f1 + f2 + f3} //depends on foo1, foo2 and foo3
} yield ()
```

Comment: Thanks for the advices. So I not do nested for loops. That is good. But I also want feature where I have third future and this depending on foo future. if foo future is completing then third future is starting. How I do this?

Comment: Do you mean when `foo` finished then second and third future should start simultaneously?

Comment: Yes. So I am having 4 futures say, foo1, foo2, foo3 and foo4. All return Future[Unit]. When no dependencies, I use for comprehension to execute them one by one. But say, foo4 depends on foo3 and foo3 depends on foo2 which depending on foo1. How write this now in for loop?

Comment: I'm sorry sir but functions cannot accepting arguments. that's my problem. It's very difficult

Comment: I doesn't matter, you can create future ad hoc inside for-comprehension.